# print() go wrong when multiple a string by any number, why does that happen?

Tags: python, cs50

when I use print() for string multiplication, it prints out an extra space (" ") at the beginning of each line. Strange. Anyone could explain why?

I was writing a Mario program with python. The program should run like this

```
$ python mario.py
Height: 4
   #
  ##
 ###
####
```

And this is my code

```
import cs50

while True:
    height = cs50.get_int("Height: ")
    if height > 0 and height < 9:
        break

for i in range(1, height + 1):
    print( " " * (height - i), "#" * i)
```

while the result gives me this

```
~/ $ python mario.py
Height: 4
    #
   ##
  ###
 ####
```

As you can see, each line has additional space in the front which shouldn't even exist.

Comment: Please try reading the [documentation for the `print` function](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#print). Do you see the `sep` argument? Do you understand what it means, when none is provided? Do you understand the effect of changing it? Hint: What do you expect will happen if you try `print('Hello', 'World')`? Now, try it. What does happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

print separates its arguments with space, your calculations are right but there's an added space.
change it to this:

```py
import cs50

while True:
    height = cs50.get_int("Height: ")
    if height > 0 and height < 9:
        break

for i in range(1, height + 1):
    print( " " * (height - i), "#" * i, sep="")
```

Comment: I'm wondering where does this added space come from

Comment: @Sherri it's default argument separator for `print` function, and for your case you should override it.

Comment: Now I see. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `f-strings`:

```
for i in range(1, height + 1):
    print(f"{'#'*i: >{height}}")
```

Output:

```
Height: 4
   #
  ##
 ###
####
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the spaces that comes before the "#"
just make the code like this

```
import cs50

while True:
    height = cs50.get_int("Height: ")
    if height > 0 and height < 9:
        break

for i in range(1, height + 1):
    print("#" * i)
```